# Apache Custom Lucene Scoring

Tags: lucene, size, similarity, scoring

I am trying to modify Lucene's default similarity score as follows. Assume each document and also the query consist of unique words. Our custom similarity score for query q and document d should be `com(d,q)/(size(d)+size(q))`. Where `com(d,q)` is the number of terms that appear in both (note that there is no duplicate term in the query and also the document). `size(d)` and `size(q)` are the number of terms in each one. We use `WhiteSpaceAnalyzer`. We assume term and document frequencies are 1, and terms are not boosted.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 2):

To apply your own scoring, you'll need to set the [`Similarity`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html) to your own implementation.  You'll want to handle the sive within the computeNorm method, which is stored at index time.  The rest should be handled by `coord`.  You could extend `TFIDFSimilarity` and get a lot of stuff for free, freeing you from having to worry about setting up your own `SimScorer`s, and such.  YOu'dd just need to stub out a lot of the functionnality.  Keep in mind it will be an extra bit of information stored with every document

So, something like:

```java
class MySimilarity extends TFIDFSimilarity {
    // 1/size(d) where size(d) is the number of terms in the Field,
    // rather than the Document (which doesn't really make sense)
    computeNorm(FieldInvertState state, Norm norm) {
        norm.setByte(encodeNorm(1 / state.getLength()));  // encodeNorm loses a great deal of precision, FYI.
    }

    // 1/size(q)
    float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
        return 1 / maxOverlap;
    }

    float idf(long docFreq, long numDocs) {
        return 1
    }

    float queryNorm(float sumOfSquaredWeights) {
        return 1;
    }

    float scorePayload(int doc, int start, int end, BytesRef payload) {
        return 1;
    }

    float sloppyFreq(int distance) {
        return 1;
    }

    float tf(float freq) {
        return 1;
    }

    float tf(int freq) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Which, I believe, should calculate scores along the lines of:

```
(1 / size(q)) * ∑ (1 / size(d))
```

Which should work out to what you are looking for.

I get a very strong feeling you are throwing the baby out with the bathwater, though.

Comment: Thanks. But it gives 1/(size(q).size(d)) ... What if I need (size(q)+size(d))?

Comment: In other words, how can I get the length of a field at the search time?

Comment: No, you got the phrasing right the first time.  Already looks like an XY problem to me, let's not move to Z now.  You store the field length in the norm, making it readily accessible in the Similarity.  To prevent the scorer multiplying scores on each matching term, you might need to implement your Similarity from scratch, and implement the SimScorers to suit.  The ExactSimScorer is probably what you'll be interested in looking into, primarily.

Comment: I think I figured out how to store the length in the norm, and still make sure it does not affect the score. But here is a question. ComputeNorm is called at the indexing time with an argument being an instance of FieldInvertState. How can I read the norm in at the search time (say in Coord function)? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can fetch the norms with [AtomicReader.normValues](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/AtomicReader.html#normValues(java.lang.String))

Comment: Any suggestions about howto access AtomicReader.normValues from coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap)?  TIA